# how to find why emacs crashes?

Tags: debugging

From time to time my emacs 29.1 crashes. This  happens essentially when using one of the menu items.

```
Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Backtrace:
emacs(+0x1b0c56)[0x56406d61bc56]
emacs(+0x4bdbe)[0x56406d4b6dbe]
emacs(+0x4cccc)[0x56406d4b7ccc]
emacs(+0x2e82ad)[0x56406d7532ad]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3e710)[0x7f6902f35710]
emacs(+0xcae89)[0x56406d535e89]
emacs(+0x1540c4)[0x56406d5bf0c4]
emacs(+0x14fd31)[0x56406d5bad31]
/usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x83ccf)[0x7f690498accf]
/usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x8baf1)[0x7f6904992af1]
/usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_display_get_event+0x99)[0x7f6904937fb9]
/usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x8bd28)[0x7f6904992d28]
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x59f69)[0x7f69042e2f69]
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0xb8327)[0x7f6904341327]
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x32)[0x7f69042e1162]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_main_iteration+0x1b)[0x7f6904bed00b]
emacs(+0x151583)[0x56406d5bc583]
emacs(+0x1a2521)[0x56406d60d521]
emacs(+0x69016)[0x56406d4d4016]
emacs(+0x19fc34)[0x56406d60ac34]
emacs(+0x1aa071)[0x56406d615071]
emacs(+0x19402f)[0x56406d5ff02f]
emacs(+0x224bf7)[0x56406d68fbf7]
emacs(+0x191afe)[0x56406d5fcafe]
emacs(+0x224b3a)[0x56406d68fb3a]
emacs(+0x193d99)[0x56406d5fed99]
emacs(+0x2fe5bb)[0x56406d7695bb]
emacs(+0x195e01)[0x56406d600e01]
emacs(+0x5d6b9)[0x56406d4c86b9]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x27cd0)[0x7f6902f1ecd0]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x8a)[0x7f6902f1ed8a]
emacs(+0x5ebd5)[0x56406d4c9bd5]
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` if Emacs crashes.

Comment: "*how to find why emacs crashes?*" -- If you want to do this job yourself, you can use GDB.